# Unzipping Files in R Using a Loop or Lapply and Saving to the Same Folder

Tags: r, loops, zip, lapply

I have a data frame that contains all of my directory and sub-directory file paths. My first dataset contains the input 'path':

```
 Input: 
 \\data\A\New Jersey\Construction\2020.10.27\Results.zip
 \\data\A\New Jersey\Materials\2020.10.27\Results.zip
 \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Construction\2020.10.27\Results.zip
 \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Electrician\2020.10.27\Results.zip
```

My second dataset contains the 'output' path:

```
   Output:
   \\data\A\New Jersey\Construction\2020.10.27
   \\data\A\New Jersey\Materials\2020.10.27
   \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Construction\2020.10.27
   \\data\A\Pennsylvania\Electrician\2020.10.27
```

As you can see, I want the files unzipped to the same folder. Currently I can use

```
   lapply(list, unzip)
```

to unzip to my working directory; however, I would like to unzip the file to the same location of the zip file.  To do this I believe that I need to use a for loop and define the exdir using the 'output' dataset.

```
    for(i in length(input)){
      for(f in length(output)){
        path <- input[i]
        out <- output[f]
        unzip(path, out) 
    }}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `mapply(unzip, zipfile = input, exdir = output)`?

Comment: I don't think mapply would would without specifying that the second vector defines the location to save the unzipped contents

Comment: I think the proposed `mapply` solution should work.  `exdir` is a parameter for `unzip`, so the proposed `mapply` should unzip the first file in `Input` to the first location in `Output`, then the second file in `Input` to the second location in `Output`.  Your nested loops would unzip the first file in `Input` to all locations in `Output`, then the second file in `Input` to all locations in `Output`.  If you want to use a for loop, the syntax would be something like `for(i in 1:length(input)) {unzip(zipfile = Input[i], exdir = Output[i])}`